# Pygame, efficient collision handling for rpg game?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I'm currently programming a little Snes-like RPG with pygame.
On my map I have 4 layers :
0 : Terrain, no collision (under char)
1 : Over Terrain no collision (under char)
2 : Collision objects (under char)
3 : Over char objects

I wanted to create a rect for every tile in my second layer which would prevent the character to go over these objects. Is there an efficient way to not check for every rectangle each time the character moves ? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pygame has a bunch of optimized functions for this, like [`Rect.collidelist`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.collidelist):

> **collidelist()**
>   *test if one rectangle in a list intersects*
>
> collidelist(list) -> index
>
> Test whether the rectangle collides with any in a sequence of rectangles. The index of the first collision found is returned. If no collisions are found an index of -1 is returned.

If you still encounter performance problems, you could use a [QuadTree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree).

[Here's an implementation in python using pygame.](http://www.pygame.org/wiki/QuadTree)

```
from pygame import Rect

class QuadTree(object):
    """An implementation of a quad-tree.

    This QuadTree started life as a version of [1] but found a life of its own
    when I realised it wasn't doing what I needed. It is intended for static
    geometry, ie, items such as the landscape that don't move.

    This implementation inserts items at the current level if they overlap all
    4 sub-quadrants, otherwise it inserts them recursively into the one or two
    sub-quadrants that they overlap.

    Items being stored in the tree must be a pygame.Rect or have have a
    .rect (pygame.Rect) attribute that is a pygame.Rect
        ...and they must be hashable.

    Acknowledgements:
    [1] http://mu.arete.cc/pcr/syntax/quadtree/1/quadtree.py
    """

    def __init__(self, items, depth=8, bounding_rect=None):
        """Creates a quad-tree.

        @param items:
            A sequence of items to store in the quad-tree. Note that these
            items must be a pygame.Rect or have a .rect attribute.

        @param depth:
            The maximum recursion depth.

        @param bounding_rect:
            The bounding rectangle of all of the items in the quad-tree. For
            internal use only.
        """

        # The sub-quadrants are empty to start with.
        self.nw = self.ne = self.se = self.sw = None

        # If we've reached the maximum depth then insert all items into this
        # quadrant.
        depth -= 1
        if depth == 0 or not items:
            self.items = items
            return

        # Find this quadrant's centre.
        if bounding_rect:
            bounding_rect = Rect( bounding_rect )
        else:
            # If there isn't a bounding rect, then calculate it from the items.
            bounding_rect = Rect( items[0] )
            for item in items[1:]:
                bounding_rect.union_ip( item )
        cx = self.cx = bounding_rect.centerx
        cy = self.cy = bounding_rect.centery

        self.items = []
        nw_items = []
        ne_items = []
        se_items = []
        sw_items = []

        for item in items:
            # Which of the sub-quadrants does the item overlap?
            in_nw = item.rect.left &lt;= cx and item.rect.top &lt;= cy
            in_sw = item.rect.left &lt;= cx and item.rect.bottom >= cy
            in_ne = item.rect.right >= cx and item.rect.top &lt;= cy
            in_se = item.rect.right >= cx and item.rect.bottom >= cy

            # If it overlaps all 4 quadrants then insert it at the current
            # depth, otherwise append it to a list to be inserted under every
            # quadrant that it overlaps.
            if in_nw and in_ne and in_se and in_sw:
                self.items.append(item)
            else:
                if in_nw: nw_items.append(item)
                if in_ne: ne_items.append(item)
                if in_se: se_items.append(item)
                if in_sw: sw_items.append(item)

        # Create the sub-quadrants, recursively.
        if nw_items:
            self.nw = QuadTree(nw_items, depth, (bounding_rect.left, bounding_rect.top, cx, cy))
        if ne_items:
            self.ne = QuadTree(ne_items, depth, (cx, bounding_rect.top, bounding_rect.right, cy))
        if se_items:
            self.se = QuadTree(se_items, depth, (cx, cy, bounding_rect.right, bounding_rect.bottom))
        if sw_items:
            self.sw = QuadTree(sw_items, depth, (bounding_rect.left, cy, cx, bounding_rect.bottom))


    def hit(self, rect):
        """Returns the items that overlap a bounding rectangle.

        Returns the set of all items in the quad-tree that overlap with a
        bounding rectangle.

        @param rect:
            The bounding rectangle being tested against the quad-tree. This
            must possess left, top, right and bottom attributes.
        """

        # Find the hits at the current level.
        hits = set( [ self.items[n] for n in rect.collidelistall( self.items ) ] )

        # Recursively check the lower quadrants.
        if self.nw and rect.left &lt;= self.cx and rect.top &lt;= self.cy:
            hits |= self.nw.hit(rect)
        if self.sw and rect.left &lt;= self.cx and rect.bottom >= self.cy:
            hits |= self.sw.hit(rect)
        if self.ne and rect.right >= self.cx and rect.top &lt;= self.cy:
            hits |= self.ne.hit(rect)
        if self.se and rect.right >= self.cx and rect.bottom >= self.cy:
            hits |= self.se.hit(rect)

        return hits
```

This will greatly improve performance over checking each tile in a simple loop.

Comment: I like the Rect.collidelist function. Will see if it does the job :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use `recs` and check to see if they collide as Dominic Kexel stated, but if your graphics are not exactly square and the collision detection needs to be perfect, that I suggest using pygame `sprite` objects with pygame masks. Masks can be set based on alpha values (transparency) and are really easy to handle:

```
class Entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image): #where image is a pygame image with that has had the convert_alpha() function used on it
        self.image = image
        self.rect = image.get_rect() #you can use a rect and a mask
        self.mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image) #creates a mask from the image ans assigns it to the sprite object
```

and then you can easily check for collions using either the `rect` attribute (there are various different types of collisions you can handle using rects) or you can check pixel perfect collisions using masks.

Any of this can be done using pygames sprite collision functions, such as `pygame.sprite.spritecollide()` or `pygame.sprite.collide_mask()` + many more!

Read up:

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html